# How to fix "missing return statement" error in java?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, return

I'm trying to make a code that will check my runner to determine whether or not the numbers are prime via a for loop. As far as I know, my runner is perfectly fine but what exactly am I supposed to return here? I have tried a boolean, a null, a "", an int and even a double.

```
public class Prime
{
    public static boolean isPrime( int num )
   {
        for(int i = 2; i<= num/2; i++)
      {
         if(num % i == 0)
         System.out.println(num + " is prime.");
         System.out.println(num + " is not prime.");   
      }
      
         // missing return statement error given here
      
   }
}
```

Comment: Err, add the missing `return` statement? or change the method to `void` if you don't want one?

Comment: Your code is wrong corrected it , do check!

Comment: @AshishMishra 'Wrongly corrected' is a contradiction in terms. Explain yourself.

Comment: You declare the method to return a boolean value, but then you don't have a return statement to return this boolean.

Comment: @user207421 what I meant was that this code will fail badly and would return true like it is checking for even numbers above 2 i.e 4,6,8,10 will become Prime and other odd will become Non-prime that is surely wrong

Comment: @AshishMishra But you didn't say that. You said 'wrongly corrected', which is meaningless. The code wasn't 'corrected' at any stage, whether 'wrongly' or otherwise. It was always wrong.

Comment: well, I think there is a difference in English meanwhile mine is British English or "Indian English" what I meant was "Your code is wrong" and "Corrected it" which means please refer to my answer that has the right code to find whether a number is a prime number or not.

Answer (score 1):

you need return boolean

```
public static boolean isPrime(int num) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= num / 2; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The code doesn't actually work correctly, but that's the OP's fault, not yours ;-)

Comment: yes, but , because I think the focus of the question  is no  "return"

Comment: I agree completely. It's his problem.